# CASE WHEN statements not returning a false

Tags: sas

I am trying to create a flag that shows a 1, when a variable `match_flg = total_match_flg`, otherwise return a 0.

When i run the following code

```
proc sql;
create table xxxxxxx as
   select*,
  CASE
  when match_flg = total_match_flg then 1 else 0
  end as keep_flg
quit;
```

it returns all 1 and am sure in the dataset that statement should false and return some 0

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Post some sample data. Otherwise we really cannot help you debug this issue.

Comment: i forgot to include a "From xxxxxxx;"  after "end as" keyword but i have it in my code

Comment: Normally when asking sql questions, it's very important to include a database/table structure, to help people determine what you do wrong. I hope this comment helps you find a solution to your issue. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `from 'datasource'` is missing. also provide the info if both `match_flg` and `total_match_flg` are of same data type.

Answer (score 2):

Is it because you're not reading any data in with a from statement?
I ran similar code (added a from) and it ran fine.

Edit: Including my test data;

```
data test;
  do i = 1 to 10;
    match_flag = i;
    total_match_flag = 10-i;
    output;
  end;

  drop i;
run;

proc sql;
  create table x as 
  select *,
  case
  when match_flag = total_match_flag then 1 else 0
  end as keep_flg
  from test;
quit;
```

As a sidenote, case can be clumsy to use. Have a look at the IFC/IFN functions instead.
http://www.lexjansen.com/wuss/2012/28.pdf